# Pagination bar in kivy

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I want to make a bottom pagination bar (Something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOnUG.png)) in my Kivy application page. By which user can easily switch to the required page number. I tried to search about it but I didn't find any relative information. Could anyone suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ScrollView` with `Button`s for all pages, or dynamically created `Button`s in a layout according to let's say current page property. Or basically anything else that would create a similar behavior.

Then bind an `on_release` event of button to a function, that will change a page. Most likely you'll end up with `ToggleButton`s, not with `Button` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @KeyWeeUsr. It helped me. :)

Comment: please give an example to illustrate